# Create/Update operations with nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I, as a newbie Django developer, am trying to build a RESTful API for a mobile app. I've took over an existing project and previous developers have used Django REST Framework. Super cool package, easy to work with so far. Except for one thing...

There is this problem when I want to create new resources, which happen to have nested serializers. I'm not great on explaining software issues with words, so here is the simplified version of my case:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()
    # other props and functions are unrelated


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # props and functions are unrelated
```

Now with this structure, `GET /users` and `GET /users/{id}` endpoints work great and I get the results I expect. But with `POST /users` and `PATCH /users/{id}` I get a response that says I need to provide an **object** for `company` prop and it should resemble a Company object with all the required props, so that it can create the company too. And I'm sure it tries to create a new company because I've tried sending `{ company: { id: 1 } }` and it simply ignores the ID and requires a `name` to create a new one. This is obviously not what I want because I just want to create a user (who may or may not belong to a company), **not** both a user and a company.

I've tried switching that `CompanySerializer` to a `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and it seems like it works on create endpoint but now I don't get the Company object on list and detail endpoints.

What am I missing here? I'm 99% sure that they did not intend this framework to work this way.

Comment: The docs might help. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: @MadWombat it doesn't. unless I'm not seeing the obvious. The part you linked says how to handle the _creation of the nested model_. I do *not* want to create a new instance of nested model.

Comment: So don't create it. The basic gist of the docs is that to handle writable nested serializers you have to override `create()` and `update()`. What you do in them is up to you.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yet the problem is that it tries to validate the data before `create()` and fails if my `company` object in POST data doesn't pass the validation to create a Company model. I will not send jibber-jabber data just to be ignored in the backend, because DRF thinks I would create a new instance of every relation for every model.

Comment: Are you sending complete company data or is it missing things? If company data in your POST/PUT is missing things you might need to override validation.

Comment: Yes, I'm only sending an ID as `company` prop. It's not even an object. I thought of overriding validation too, but at that point I'm rewriting so much of the functionality that DRF should provide out-of-the-box that I'd be better off to just do everything in plain Django. I'm going with Daniel's suggestion for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am currently working on a DRF based project and "why am I bothering with this instead of implementing things in plain Django" is my sentiment as well :)

Comment: That said, all you really need is to implement `to_internal_value()` where you do your own validation and manipulate the data as you see fit

Comment: Another option is to try and set read_only=True on your nested fields

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `create()` and `update()` methods on nested serializers to make them writable. Otherwise DRF is not sure what to do with nested objects. The simplest override would go something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = instance
        user.__dict__.update(validated_data)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Note: haven't tested this variant of `update()` might need adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a different serializer class for retrieving vs updating - one with a PrimaryKeyRelatedField and one with a nested serializer. You can override `get_serializer_class` to do this. Assuming you are using a viewset:

```
class BaseUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (...)

class WriteUserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()

class ReadUserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    company = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ["create", "update", "partial_update", "destroy"]:
            return WriteUserSerializer
        else:
            return ReadUserSerializer
```

Comment: Really? That sounds so cumbersome to be honest. I would have expected the framework to handle those different operations. Nevertheless, thanks for your input. I would never come to this conclusion by myself.